# What time format is "2018-06-29T08:51:00Z"? Can you tell me what format string should I use in moment.js to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetime-format

I have used `moment(dateFromAPI,"YYYY-MM-DD")` to parse the date, and it gives the date in format "2018-06-29T18:30:00.000Z".

But I need to send the date in "2018-06-29T08:51:00Z" format.

> Can anyone explain to me what is this "2018-06-29T08:51:00Z" format?
>   
>   and what format string should I use to achieve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a full ISO-8601 date/time in UTC. It's one of the few formats you can reliably and correctly pass to `moment` without a format string:

```
var m = moment("2018-06-29T18:30:00.000Z");
```

That's because it's in [the only format that JavaScript's `Date` object is required to support](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). (But that section, introduced in ES2015, had to be amended in ES2016 and ES2017, and note that when there isn't a timezone indicator on the string [there is in yours, `Z`], date-only strings are interpreted as UTC and date/time strings as local time, which is not the same as ISO-8601.)

You can produce your string without milliseconds with [`utc`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) and [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) and adding `Z` at the end:

```
console.log(m.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z"); // "2018-06-29T18:30:00.000Z"
```

Example:

```js
var m = moment("2018-06-29T18:30:00.000Z");
console.log(m.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") + "Z"); // "2018-06-29T18:30:00.000Z"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

More in [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: @mukesh.kumar - I missed that you were leaving out the milliseconds, updated.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. Although I tried what you previously mentioned. I did `console.log(m.utc().format())` and it worked. I was able to send time to the API endpoint.